# Oracle foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle, alter

So i have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE Client(
ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL, (PRIMARY KEY)
Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Surname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Phone NUMBER(11) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR(70));

CREATE TABLE Boss(
B_Surname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, (PRIMARY KEY)
B_Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);
```

I need to put foreign key (B_surname from Boss table) to Client table. I've tried use ALTER TABLE:

```
ALTER TABLE Client ADD CONSTRAINT Boss_Client_fk FOREIGN KEY (B_Surname) REFERENCES Client(ID);
```

After that I got errors. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: Your alter table statement doesn't mention the Boss table. Can't work. Check the docs for the syntax.

Comment: @Mat Thanks for reply, can you write how it should be, becouse i have checked syntax, i don't understand it.

Comment: It always helps to say *which* errors you got. As Mat said, you should be doing `alter table boss`, not `alter table client`. But why are you trying to make the string `b_surname` column reference the numeric `id`?

Comment: I think he means for the column `b_surname` in `CLIENT` to reference the similarly-named column in `BOSS`: `ALTER TABLE Client ADD CONSTRAINT Boss_Client_fk FOREIGN KEY (B_Surname) REFERENCES boss (b_surname);`

Comment: That `PRIMARY KEY` syntax is a bit odd too. Looks like extraneous commas at the very least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the following. Please note that you should probably be using `VARCHAR2` rather than `VARCHAR` in Oracle. They work the same at the moment but there is a possibility that Oracle will change the functionality for `VARCHAR` to bring it in line with the ANSI standard (in which empty strings `''` are distinguished from `NULL`s ... but I digress):

```
CREATE TABLE client
( id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
, surname VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
, phone NUMBER(11) NOT NULL
, email VARCHAR2(70) );

CREATE TABLE boss
( b_surname VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, b_Name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL );
```

And then:

```
ALTER TABLE client ADD CONSTRAINT boss_client_fk FOREIGN KEY (surname) REFERENCES boss (b_surname);
```

It's a bit odd that the column is named `surname` in `CLIENT` and `b_surname` in `BOSS`.

If you want `b_surname` in `BOSS` to refer to `surname` in `CLIENT` -- then you need to make `CLIENT.surname` a primary key, or at least unique.