# foreign key not adding to booking table, can anyone spot the issue

Tags: sql, oracle

```
  Create table Hotel (
    Hotel_no varchar (10) NOT NULL,
    Hotel_name varchar (10) NOT NULL,
    Address varchar (600) NOT NULL,
    Primary key (Hotel_no) );


    Create table Room (
    Room_no varchar (10) NOT NULL,
    Hotel_no varchar (10) NOT NULL,
    type varchar (40) NOT NULL,
    price varchar (20) NOT NULL,
    Primary key (Room_no, Hotel_no) );


    Create table Guest (
    Guest_no varchar (10) NOT NULL,
    Guest_name varchar (10) NOT NULL,
    Address varchar (600) NOT NULL,
    Primary key (Guest_no) );


    Create table Booking (
    date_from date,
    date_to date,
    Hotel_no varchar (10) NOT NULL,
    Guest_no varchar (10) NOT NULL,
    Room_no varchar (10) NOT NULL,
    Primary key (date_from, Hotel_no, Guest_no),
    Foreign key(Room_no)references Room(Room_no));
```

when i try adding the foreign key to the booking table it gives an ORA-02270 error, and i cant seem to figure out the problem
any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why do you store the numbers in `varchar` fields?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28015447/5533075) and use `VARCHAR2` instead of `VARCHAR`

Comment: What does the error ORA-02270 mean?

Answer (score 1):

Your foreign key on `Room` should reference the primary key `Room(Room_no,  Hotel_no)`

Answer (score 0):

If the primary key is a set of columns then the foreign key should also be a set of columns corresponding to the composite key columns.
Try below code :

```
Create table Booking ( date_from date, date_to date, Hotel_no varchar (10) NOT NULL, Guest_no varchar (10) NOT NULL, Room_no varchar (10) NOT NULL, Primary key (date_from, Hotel_no, Guest_no), Foreign key(Room_no,Hotel_no)references Room(Room_no,Hotel_no);
```

Comment: Glad to know that :)